# Just defining a Qt-slot with a certain parameter causes a runtime exception

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake, linker

While developing a Qt6 application that uses opencv, I stumbled upon a bug that I don't understand. I've simplified the code as much as possible:

*(CMakeLists.txt)*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(OpenCVTest)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Multimedia Test)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

add_executable(MainApp main.cpp)
target_include_directories(MainApp PRIVATE ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(MainApp PRIVATE Qt6::Multimedia ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

*(main.cpp)*

```cpp
#include <QObject>
#include <QMediaPlayer>
#include <iostream>

enum SomeOtherEnum {
    VAL0, VAL1, VAL2
};

class SomeRandomObject: public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SomeRandomObject(QObject* parent = nullptr): QObject(parent) {}
    ~SomeRandomObject() {}
private slots:
    void causesBadAlloc(const QMediaPlayer::PlaybackState state) {}
    void worksJustFine(const SomeOtherEnum state){}
};

#include "main.moc"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::cout << "[success]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this file, there are no errors. When I start it however, I get a bad_alloc exception immediately. I created a small docker container that represents my system configuration.

```
FROM archlinux:base-devel

RUN set -ex; \
    pacman -Syu --noconfirm; \
    pacman -S --noconfirm opencv qt6-base qt6-multimedia cmake; \
    pacman -S --noconfirm --asdeps vtk glew qt5-base hdf5 opencl-icd-loader openmpi fmt

RUN mkdir src build

CMD cmake -Bbuild -Hsrc && cmake --build build --target MainApp && build/MainApp || echo "[error]"
```

When I build and run this container:

```bash
docker build -t opencv_test .
docker run --rm -v$(pwd):/src opencv_test
```

I always get a segmentation fault or this exception:

```bash
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

If I comment out the `causesBadAlloc(...)` slot or don't use `${OpenCV_LIBS}`, everything works fine. Does anyone know what the issue is and how I can have a slot with parameters like `causesBadAlloc(...)` without causing a bad_alloc exception?

Comment: Such "random" behaviour can easily occur if you have a memory leak somewhere. In of the two builds, the accessed memory address is still in you program memory area and in the other build it's not. Another typical reason could be accessing uninitialized variables, which will have the value of the memory, where menory addresses will be different on both builds.

Comment: i believe this is related to library linking issue